# Remove carriage return / Line feeds in string and output with quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL that outputs a string with double quotes around it:

```
SELECT '"'+A.DESCR+'"'
FROM MyTable

Results:
"Stackable Storage Basket"
```

I have found that I have carriage returns / line feeds in some of the data and want to remove any of these while retaining the quotes. I have modified the code as below, however this is adding an extra quote onto the end of the string, and not retaining the beginning quote either.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(DESCR + '"'+DESCR+'"' + '''', char(10),'"'), char(13), '"')
FROM MyTable

Results:
Stackable Storage Basket"'
```

How do I need to modify this to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't you be replacing the characters with `''` *not* `'"'`? It looks like your just overly complicating the issue. it should just be `'"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(DESCR, CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') + '"'`

Comment: I have modified as this: `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('"'+DESCR+'"' + '''', char(10),''), char(13), '')`  but it is now adding an extra single quote character onto the end i.e - "Stackable Storage Basket"'

Comment: It's not "adding one" at all, @Nick, it's in your data.

Comment: Yes your right! Didnt see all of your first comment, thanks!

Comment: But why do you need to put double quotes around it?

Comment: Also what if the data has `"` in it. You'll end up with `"something"else"` - will this not screw up whatever is consuming this data?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? If you are using this to generate a CSV then you're doing it wrong